# PowerShell | Get-ChildItem to Function via Pipeline not providing all items

Tags: powershell

Due to Azure Dev Ops converting LF to CRLF on deployment I have to create a custom function that will search for .sh files and convert them back to how they are stored in the repo (LF). That code I got down fine however I REALLY want to make a awesome function I can do a single get-childitem recursive looking for .sh files and then pipe that to my custom function that will turn them back to the correct format.

My problem is that me, get-childitem, and functions arent not getting along.

To keep this focused on just the main issue here is an over simplistic example function:

```
Function List-Items {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$items
    )

    Write-Output "Item Count: $($items | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count)"
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        Write-Output "Item: $($item)"
    }
}
```

I call it using:

`dir c:\temp\ | List-Items`

Yet even though there are clearly 52 items via this command: 
`dir c:\temp\ | Measure-Object`

The function only sees the last record of those 52. How do I access all 52 within my custom list-items function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. In reality, an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) in PowerShell has [*three* distinct blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods#input-processing-methods):

- `begin` - Runs once, before the pipeline starts executing
- `process` - Runs once *for each pipeline-bound input item*
- `end` - Runs once *after* the upstream cmdlet is done sending input

When you don't specify any of these distinct blocks, but just have a single function body, like your example:

```
Function List-Items {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$items
    )

    # Do stuff with $items

}
```

It's actually equivalent to:

```
Function List-Items {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$items
    )

    end {
        # Do stuff with $items
    }
}
```

In other words, the function body defaults to act as the `end` block, which is why you're only seeing the last value bound to `$items`.

To fix this, explicitly specify a `process` block:

```
Function List-Items {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$items
    )

    process {
        foreach ($item in $items) {
            Write-Output "Item: $($item)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems so simple now but I did google this for some time and the keywords I was using just didnt get me anywhere near the need for proper function structure. Codes working!

Comment: @EricWeintraub You're most welcome! And yeah, it can definitely be tricky to discover if you don't know what terms to search for. The `about_*` help files are almost _always_ the best place to start!

Answer (score 1):

You need a process block that runs once for each item piped.

```
function hi { 
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]$inputvalue)

  process { 
    $inputvalue.count 
  } 

}

1,2,3 | hi

1
1
1
```